# Should the "savings" and "saving" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't have enough reputation in either tag to suggest one as a synonym of the other, but I don't think it's necessary to have both. The [savings](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/savings) tag is used on 145 questions, while the [saving](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saving) tag is only used on 33 questions. Would it make sense to merge the latter into the former, perhaps?

Comment: I guess yes, there are other suggested synonyms that are pending approval. Maybe the moderators can approver these as well http://money.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I've performed the merge.  In the future, please don't edit questions to change a tag when there are many to edit, because that bumps them all to the home page.  If there are just a few it's OK, but say, greater than ~10, please let us perform the merge so we can avoid the home page bump on all the affected questions.

Comment: Also worth noting: Editing the old tag away to replace with the new doesn't set up the tag synonym, which prevents the old tag from being used again.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Thank you. Apologies on the edits; I'll keep that in mind the next time. I didn't have the reputation to suggest a synonym, so in the future I'll stick to posting on meta (without all the edits).

Comment: I was about to ask whether users actually paid enough attention to differentiate between the two, i.e. for "saving" to mean the ongoing process of putting money aside, and "savings" to discuss the actual pot of gold accumulated. But as the merge is now complete, uh, never mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concur: merge them.  I only see upsides.

At best, the difference in meaning is trivial and using one over the other would not cause confusion for searches and classification.

At worst, the question author deliberates over [savings](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/savings) and [saving](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saving) wondering if there really *is* a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure how to merge tags, but I notice other tags that are somewhat redundant, like [tag:retirement] and [tag:retirement-plan].

Comment: @JohnBensin Those tags aren't exactly synonymous.  *Retirement planning* is practiced by the non-retired; i.e. it is forward-looking.  Whereas, different financial issues can arise when already in retirement.  Merging tags is appropriate when the tags mean *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Thanks for letting me know; I wasn't sure, since they only seemed partially redundant. Is merging tags something only higher-reputation users can do, or is there a menu somewhere that I missed?

Comment: @MrChrister I second the motion to merge these tags.

Comment: @JohnBensin I'm under the impression the actual merging of tags is a moderator-only activity.